# MS Access combo box value list

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a combo box with lots of values in it. As I type in some text it jumps to some value in list which starts with the text I entered, which is normal. But is it possible to jump to value which also contains the text I entered? For example, I type in "ember" it offers me the value "December" which is in the list. Im sorry if Im not clear enough..

Comment: Yes, but you need to code it in VBA. Consider OnChange event and the .text property of the combo. A listbox might be easier.

Comment: Ok, thanks for idea. Since Im quite a beginner in VBA any further help would be appreciated.. :)

Comment: Set the recordsource of the combo in the onchange event to an sql statement eg `SELECT f1,f2 FROM table1 WHERE f1 LIKE '*' & Forms!form1!Text1.Text & '*'` Use the query design window to get your statement right.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but the problem is, when it also starts with that text, it only offers 1 value, but there are more with same first symbols.

Comment: You have only minimal information in your question and no sample code, so I am afraid that is as far as I go. You can improve you question with sample data and sample code.